# cmd doesn't recognize casper.start()

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

```
phantom.casperPath=('C:\Users\lee0\Desktop\casperjs-1.1.4-1\casperjs-1.1.4- 
1');
phantom.injectJs('C:\Users\lee0\Desktop\casperjs-1.1.4-1\casperjs-1.1.4- 
1\bin\bootstrap.js');

var fs=require('fs')

var casper = require('casper').create()({
pageSettings: {
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'
}
});

//open Facebook
casper.start().thenOpen("https://dcid.dcinside.com/join/login.php?", 
function() {
console.log("Facebook website opened");
});

//로그인
casper.then(function(){
console.log("해당 id와 pw로 로그인 합니다.");
this.evaluate(function(){
    document.getElementById("user_id").value="chermy018";
        document.getElementById("password").value="kl424321";
        document.getElementById("login_ok").children[1].click();
});
});

var request = require('request'),
cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = "http://gallog.dcinside.com/inc/_mylog.php? 
gid=chermy018&oneview=Y&cid=59&page=1";

request(url, function(err, res, html) {
if (!err) {
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
}
console.log(html);
})

casper.run();
```

TypeError: undefined is not a constructor evaluating casper.start(). 
i already posted same question of above texts. i added comments that it's seems i have problem with installation of casperjs because other proper codes also doesn't work resulting "undefined is not a constructor evaluating casper.start()". just in case of possibility of ask, i post same question.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to reqrite your question because currently it's hard to understand what you're asking about. Please only write about what technical issues you have (the purpose of a scraper is unimportant). Also: do you somehow use node.js?

Comment: i installed casperjs and phantomjs respectively in path of C:\Users\lee0\Desktop\casperjs-1.1.4-1, C:\Users\lee0\Desktop\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows. and i added each path of casperjs and phantomjs to path which was environment variables. when i checked version of each it in cmd worked well. but same problem i questioned was appeared when i run codes after that.

Comment: So you can run `casperjs --version` and `phantomjs --version` and it works, right? Now, please show how you run your script.

Comment: Also: no need to set phantom.casperPath if you've placed binaries locations in PATH

Comment: i ran my script by commend 'phantomjs text2.js'. i saved script by the name of text2 at C:\nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is written for CasperJS, but you've ran it via PhantomJS, which is incorrect. Instead you should run it this way (supposing CasperJS is in PATH):

```
casperjs text2.js
```